# JQuery Mobile showPageLoadingMsg not displaying when i expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

new to JQM, trying to figure out why the alert fires before the page loading message appears. I'm sure I have a fundamental misunderstanding of JQM here, but I cannot figure this one out.

```
function onDeviceReady() {

   $mobile.showPageLoadingMsg("b", "Loading...", true);

   for (i=0;i<10000000;i++){
        // simulating work to be done
   }

   alert("hello");


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things it may be.

1. In the current version of JQM that method is no longer the way to show the loading msg. It is now $.mobile.loading('show') and $.mobile.loading('hide')
2. If you are using an old version of JQM that still supports the method your using then you have a slight error in your code. It should be $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg("b", "Loading...", true); You were missing a . between $ and mobile.